# displaying mysql column names in an array along with its data

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to fetch records from `MySql` and display them in an `array` along with column headers using `PDO`, reason I am doing this is because i want to export them in an excel and I am using [php-excel](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/)

right now the following code displays the records perfectly fine in an array and I am able to export them just fine

```
    while ($row[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $data = $row;
    endwhile;
```

The array i get as a result of above code is as following

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [fname] => First Name
            [lname] => Last Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 91
            [fname] => First Name
            [lname] => Last Name
        )
)
```

But the problem is I am missing column headers in excel, so for that I need to display the `MySql` column headers in an array as well.

I am using the following code to create an array for column headers

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
        $col = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
        $columns[] = $col['name'];
    }
```

but this gives me an array in following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => user_id
    [1] => fname
    [2] => lname
)
```

whereas I need the column header array in following format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => user_id
            [fname] => fname
            [lname] => lname
        )
)
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the headers to be in the same array. In that case you would do this **before** the while loop

```
$data[0] = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $col = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    $data[0][$col['name']] = $col['name'];
}
```

Also, the while loop is a little inefficient. You're pushing each row into the `$row` array and then copying it into `$data` every single time. It should be done like this instead:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
    $data[] = $row;
endwhile;
```

This should get you:

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => user_id
        [fname] => fname
        [lname] => lname
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => value...
        ...
    )
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting it auto-number, just provide the name again as the key:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $stmt->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $col = $stmt->getColumnMeta($i);
    $columns[$col['name']] = $col['name'];
}
```

Example: https://eval.in/117424

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if(!isset($data)) {
        $data[] = array_combine(array_keys($row), array_keys($row));
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Or you could add them after the fact using `array_unshift()`.

Or in a separate array:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if(!isset($col)) {
        $col[] = array_combine(array_keys($row), array_keys($row));
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Indeed another way of doing it, that's why I love stackoverflow, brilliant solutions by brilliant minds